# UITableViewCell animation issue in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios8

I am trying to expand a `UITableViewCell` when tapped on it. I use the reload sections method in tableview did select row and change the height of the cell in Height for row at indexpath . It was working fine ,until i tested my app in iOS8 yesterday . For some reason the animation has become quite jaggy in iOS 8 .Please find below the code im using .

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    if(self.selectedOrder.section == indexPath.section) {

        self.shouldRevealCell = NO;
        self.selectedOrder = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:-1 inSection:-1];
    }
    else {

        self.lastSelectedOrder = self.selectedOrder;
        self.shouldRevealCell = YES;
        self.selectedOrder = indexPath;
    }


    [self.orderDockTableView beginUpdates];
    [self.orderDockTableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [self.orderDockTableView endUpdates];


    if(indexPath.section == ([self.orderObjectsArray count] -1)) {
        [self.orderDockTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
    }

}

// Height For Row at index path
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if(indexPath.section == self.selectedOrder.section) {
        return 133.0f;
    }

    return 85.0f;

}
```

Im using two images ..one for the collapsed state and one for the expanded state.One more thing i have done is applying a corner radius to my `UITableViewCell` to make it look like rounded rect ,not sure if it is causing the problem but the animation in iOS8 is very jerky , The cell moves towards right before expanding and is not smooth at all. Unfortunately i cant post a pic/gif as a newbie to this site.